# Entity Framework relate second table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, api, fluent

How can I relate the tables below by fluent api?

I need to get the second table data via `LinkTable` which stores ids of `Main` and `Second` tables.

[image]

Here are my models:

```
public class MainTable
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        ...
        ...
        public ICollection<LinkTable> LinkTable { get; set; }
}

public class LinkTable
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        ...
        ...
        public MainTable MainTable  { get; set; }
        public SecondTable SecondTable { get; set; }
}

public class SecondTable
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        ...
        ...
        public ICollection<LinkTable> LinkTable { get; set; }
}
```

I mapped like this:

```
HasRequired(t => t.MainTable).WithMany(t => t.LinkTable).HasForeignKey(t => t.MainTable_ID);
HasRequired(t => t.SecondTable).WithMany(t => t.LinkTable).HasForeignKey(t => t.SecondTable_ID);
```

And trying to get data :

```
MyDBContext.MainTable.Include("LinkTable").FirstOrDefault();
```

When I was trying foreach the `LinkTable` to get `SecondTable` data I got an error:

> Object reference not set...

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.LinkTable)
 {
     <p>@item.SecondTable.ID</p>
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid that exception, you need to initialize your navigation property in a constructor:

```
public class MainTable
{

    public MainTable()
    {
      LinkTable=new List<LinkTable>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    public ICollection<LinkTable> LinkTable { get; set; }
}
```

Also, you could use [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.113).aspx) extension method which is strongly typed and could avoid you possible run-time exceptions:

```
MyDBContext.MainTable.Include(mt=>mt.LinkTable).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now if you want to load another level, in this case `SecondTable`, you can do this:

```
MyDBContext.MainTable.Include(mt=>mt.LinkTable.Select(lt=>lt.SecontTable)).FirstOrDefault();
```

In the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.113).aspx) I quoted above you can find more examples about how to load different levels.

Comment: I can call the linktable, but can't  the second:

Comment: And did you check if you have a `SencondTable` related with that `LinkTable` in your DB?